# UIImage adding image as subView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I need add subView image to UIImage.

How can I do it?

Comment: YouTube, Google, Apple Developer, Mac Rumours, Stack Overflow all have examples (whether tutorials or as parts of other tutorials). Have a look at them.

Comment: The method is called `addSubview:`.  The answer is literally in the question.  Objective-C method names are extraordinarily far from cryptic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overlay one image over another in a single image, make an image graphics context, draw the first image, then draw the second image, and now extract the resulting image which now contains both of them (and close the graphics context).

Comment: See, for instance, the second example in my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_uiimage_drawing